# Can I collect data submitted from the form I built with Cognito Forms on my own database?

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a site, on this site for Secondary or College students, I want to include forms where students can register with unique ID issued by the school. After registration they can **login** to their accounts and update their data. I want a form too for course registration where they will register their courses and after exams they can print their results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You can have data sent out of Cognito Forms to your own systems or other systems in a number of different ways.

You can set up a [JSON end point](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/66/data-integration/webhooks) that will send the form data over to a url for another system. As long as the system is set up to receive JSON data, you will then be able to use that data.

You can also set up connections between Cognito Forms and other systems using applications like [Zapier](https://zapier.com) and [Microsoft Flow](https://us.flow.microsoft.com). You can have the data sent out of Cognito Forms and into other systems based on triggers set up in the Zapier or Flow connection.